# group by first column, and split (pivot?) remaining two columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

TSQL question here. See source and desired output in image below.  Code to build source table is also provided.

[image]

---

```
DECLARE @tablevar TABLE(
record nvarchar(10),
category nvarchar(50),
value float)

INSERT INTO @tablevar
VALUES
('110-AL','credits_cle',1),
('110-AL','credits_ethics',2),
('110-AR','credits_ethics',2.5),
('110-AZ','credits_prof_resp',1.5),
('110-AZ', 'credits_ethics',5),
('110-AZ', 'credits_cle',4)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want to PIVOT two columns of data, one way you can do this would be to apply both the UNPIVOT and the PIVOT functions.  The UNPIVOT will convert the multiple columns `category` and `value` to multiple rows, then you can apply the PIVOT to get the final result:

```
select record, 
  category1, value1, 
  category2, value2, 
  category3, value3
from
(
  select record, col+cast(seq as varchar(10)) col, val
  from
  (
    select record, category, 
      cast(value as nvarchar(50)) value,
      row_number() over(partition by record order by category) seq
    from tablevar
  ) d
  unpivot
  (
    val
    for col in (category, value)
  ) unpiv
) src
pivot
(
  max(val)
  for col in (category1, value1, category2, value2, category3, value3)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5671/4).

If you have an unknown number of values, then you will have to use dynamic SQL similar to this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(col+cast(seq as varchar(10))) 
                    from
                    (
                      select row_number() over(partition by record order by category) seq
                      from tablevar
                    ) d
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'category', 1 union all
                      select 'value', 2
                    ) c (col, so)
                    group by seq, so, col
                    order by seq, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT record,' + @cols + ' 
             from 
             (
               select record, col+cast(seq as varchar(10)) col, val
                from
                (
                  select record, category, 
                    cast(value as nvarchar(50)) value,
                    row_number() over(partition by record order by category) seq
                  from tablevar
                ) d
                unpivot
                (
                  val
                  for col in (category, value)
                ) unpiv
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(val)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5671/6)

Comment: Impressive answer, and you included dynamic sql for unknown number of categories per record.  Thank you, and thanks to the others for their attempts!

Comment: the first part blows my mind: you unpivot an non-pivot-table to then pivot it. you are using the rownumber to increment the names of the fields. i am playing around with it right now. understanding this shall be my weekend exercise;)

Answer (score 2):

This being the first time I've used PIVOT, the code is probably pretty ugly. Here goes:

```
with ranked as (
    select *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION by record ORDER by category) as r
    from @tablevar
), labeled as (
    select record, category as content, 'category' + CAST(r as varchar(MAX)) as label
     from ranked
    union all
    select record, cast(value AS nvarchar(MAX)),  'value' + CAST(r as varchar(MAX)) as label
     from ranked) --select * from labeled
select record, [category1] as [category], [value1] as [value], [category2] as [category], [value2] as [value], [category3] as [category], [value3] as [value]
from (SELECT * FROM labeled) as source
PIVOT(
    max(content)
    for label in ([category1], [value1], [category2], [value2], [category3], [value3])) as pvt
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my stab at it

```
;with Z as
(
select record, category, value,  ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by record order by category) as ranker
from @tablevar
) 
select Z2.record, Z2.c1, Z3.v1, Z2.c2, Z3.v2, Z2.c3, Z3.v3 from 
(
select  record, [1] c1, [2] c2, [3] c3 from 
(select record, category, ranker from Z) as Z0
pivot
( min(category) for ranker in ([1], [2], [3])) as pvt
) Z2

join
(
select  record, [1] v1, [2] v2, [3] v3 from 
(select record, value, ranker from Z) as Z1
pivot
( min(value) for ranker in ([1], [2], [3])) as pvt
) Z3 
on Z2.record = Z3.record
```